# Convert Mainframe SORT to Shell Script

Tags: shell, mainframe

Is there any easy way to convert JCL SORT to Shell Script?

Here is the JCL SORT:

```
OPTION ZDPRINT
SORT FIELDS=(15,1,CH,A)
SUM FIELDS=(16,8,25,8,34,8,43,8,52,8,61,8),FORMAT=ZD
OUTREC BUILD=(14X,15,54,13X)
```

Only bytes 15 for a length of 54 are relevant from the input data, which is the key and the source values for the summation. Others bytes from the input are not important.

Assuming the data is printable.

The data is sorted on the one-byte key, and each value for records with the same key is summed, separately, for each of the six numbers. A single record is written, per key, with the summed values and with other data (those one bytes in between and at the end) from the *first* record. The sort is "unstable" (meaning that the order of records presented to the summation is not reproduceable from one execution to the next) so the byte values should theoretically be the same on all records, or be irrelevant.

The output, for each key, is presented as a record containing 14 blanks (14X) then the 54 bytes starting at position 15 (which is the one-byte key) and then followed by 13 blanks (13X). The numbers should be right-aligned and left-zero-filled [OP to confirm, and amend sample data and expected output].

Assuming the sum will only contain positive number and will not be signed, and that for any number which is less than 999999990 there will be leading zeros for any unused positions (numbers are character, right-aligned and left-zero-filled).

Assuming the one-byte key will only be alphabetic.

The data has already been converted to ASCII from EBCDIC.

Sample Input:

```
00000000000000A11111111A11111111A11111111A11111111A11111111A111111110000000000000
00000000000000B22222222A22222222A22222222A22222222A22222222A222222220000000000000
00000000000000C33333333A33333333A33333333A33333333A33333333A333333330000000000000
00000000000000A44444444B44444444B44444444B44444444B44444444B444444440000000000000
```

Expected Output:

```
              A55555555A55555555A55555555A55555555A55555555A55555555             
              B22222222A22222222A22222222A22222222A22222222A22222222             
              C33333333A33333333A33333333A33333333A33333333A33333333
```

(14 preceding blanks and 13 trailing blanks)

Expected Volume: tenth thousands

Comment: Depends. SyncSORT runs on other platforms. Micro Focus have an emulator. Either of those any good to you? You'd best update your question with exactly what that is doing, if you're asking for someone to give you the code in on whatever OS you are using.

Comment: yes please share what the function doing and output is required in which format?

Comment: @ShravanYadav there you go. However, I'd wait for OP to insert the details, as otherwise you may end up doing it twice :-)

Comment: OK, so now do your bit @William LAM.

Comment: The question is updated accordingly. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem. Shellers let rip...

Comment: can you provide sample input data and output data. It will help in testing the code.

Comment: Also expected volume of records for the file. For some smaller (relative term) number of records, an associative-array/hash would do, but with a few hundred million records another approach may be better.

Comment: @ShravanYadav Sample input and expected output added for your information please.

Comment: @BillWoodger expected volume will be tenth thousands.

Comment: Can you add that to the question, please. It is much easier for someone to see it there than pick it up from the comments.

Comment: Question updated. Thanks.

Comment: what will be output for line  00000000000000D44444444D44444444D44444444D44444444D44444444D444444440000000000000

Comment: @ShravanYadav D44444444D44444444D44444444D44444444D44444444D44444444 with preceding and trailing blanks.

Comment: Can you check the latest edit, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured an answer:

```
awk -v FIELDWIDTHS="14 1 8 1 8 1 8 1 8 1 8 1 8 13" \
'{if(!($2 in a)) {a[$2]=$2; c[$2]=$4; e[$2]=$6; g[$2]=$8; i[$2]=$10; k[$2]=$12} \
b[$2]+=$3; d[$2]+=$5; f[$2]+=$7; h[$2]+=$9; j[$2]+=$11; l[$2]+=$13;} END \
{for(id in a) printf("%14s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%13s\n","",a[id],b[id],c[id],d[id],e[id],f[id],g[id],h[id],i[id],j[id],k[id],l[id],"");}' input
```

Explaination:

1) Split the string

```
awk -v FIELDWIDTHS="14 1 8 1 8 1 8 1 8 1 8 1 8 13"
```

2) Let $2 be the key and $4, $6, $8, $10, $12 will only set value for the first time

```
{if(!($2 in a)) {a[$2]=$2; c[$2]=$4; e[$2]=$6; g[$2]=$8; i[$2]=$10; k[$2]=$12}
```

3) Others will be summed up

```
b[$2]+=$3; d[$2]+=$5; f[$2]+=$7; h[$2]+=$9; j[$2]+=$11; l[$2]+=$13;} END
```

4) Print for each key

```
{for(id in a) printf("%14s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%13s\n","",a[id],b[id],c[id],d[id],e[id],f[id],g[id],h[id],i[id],j[id],k[id],l[id],"");}
```

Comment: You'll make it much clearer if you put it in a file and give it some nice formatting. If performance is an issue, use the core-utils sort and pipe the sorted file into an AWK/Perl/something which does the totalling.You could consider cutting down the size of the file first.

Answer (score 0):

okay I have tried something

1) extracting duplicate keys from file and storing it in duplicates file.

```
awk '{k=substr($0,1,15);a[k]++}END{for(i in a)if(a[i]>1)print i}' sample > duplicates
```

OR

```
awk '{k=substr($0,1,15);print k}' sample | sort | uniq -c | awk '$1>1{print $2}'  > duplicates
```

2) For duplicates, doing the calculation and creating newfile with specificied format

```
while read line
do 
grep ^$line sample | awk -F[A-Z] -v key=$line '{for(i=2;i<=7;i++)f[i]=f[i]+$i}END{printf("%14s"," ");for(i=2;i<=7;i++){printf("%s%.8s",substr(key,15,1),f[i]);if(i==7)printf("%13s\n"," ")}}' > newfile
done < duplicates
```

3) for unique ones,format and append to newfile

```
grep -v -f duplicates sample | sed 's/0/ /g' >> newfile  ## gives error if 0 is within data instead of start and end in a row.
```

OR

```
grep -v -f duplicates sample | awk '{printf("%14s%s%13s\n"," ",substr($0,15,54)," ")}' >> newfile
```

if you have any doubt, let me know.

Comment: The key is 15,1 not 1,15. Of course there will be zeros in the data. The number 17 will be appearing as 00000017. Need to update the question for that. Can't you limit to the columns? Not even that is needed. Remember that the beginning and end of the data can be ignored, as you do in your OR for number 3. Why not just do the lot in AWK?

Comment: This is a bit complicated. Need some time to read the script. But thank you for your help!